# OpenGL is not rendering my cube

Tags: c++, opengl

I have recently started learning OpenGL with the tutorial on http://www.opengl-tutorial.org. The first few tutorials went fine, and I got my triangle on the screen. Now I moved on to the cube tutorial, but I got stuck on the following problem. I only made 2 big changes to the triangle program to render my cube:

- I changed the triangle to a cube by adding more vertices
- I moved all of the initializing code from my main function into different other functions.

The problem is that when I run the program, it compiles fine and shows me a dark blue screen (the color I had set for clearing the screen), but it doesn't render my cube.

My full code is here:

```
#include "common/shader/loadShader.h"
#include "common/logpp/log++.h"

#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\glfw3.h>

#include <vector>

logpp::FileLog mainLog;

//Contains all functions for initializing OpenGL, GLEW and GLFW
namespace GLInit
{


    void SetGLFWWindowHints()
    {
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); /*OpenGL 3.3*/
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
#ifdef __APPLE__
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    }

    void InitGLFW()
    {
        if (!glfwInit())
        {
            logpp::Console::error("Failed to initialize GLFW!");
            return;
        }


        SetGLFWWindowHints();
    }

    void InitGLEW()
    {
        glewExperimental = true; //Needed in core profile
        if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        {
            logpp::Console::error("Failed to initialize GLEW!");
            return;
        }
    }

    GLuint CreateVAO()
    {
        GLuint VertexArrayID;
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
        glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

        return VertexArrayID;
    }

    GLFWwindow* CreateWin(int width, int height, char const* caption)
    {
        auto window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, caption, nullptr, nullptr);
        if (window == nullptr)
        {
            std::string msg = "Failed to create window!";
            logpp::Console::error(msg);
            mainLog.write("[ERROR]: " + msg);
            glfwTerminate();
            return nullptr;
        }

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

        return window;
    }

    GLFWwindow* Init(int width, int height, char const* caption)
    {

        InitGLFW();

        auto window = CreateWin(width, height, caption);

        InitGLEW();

        return window;
    }

}

using namespace GLInit;


int main()
{
    static const int VERTICES_IN_TRIANGLE = 3;


    PathConverter::setBase(R"(C:\Users\michi_000\Desktop\C++\OpenGL\A Colored Cube\x64\Debug\)");

    try
    {
        mainLog.open(PathConverter::convert("logs\\main.log"), false);

    }
    catch (logpp::FileLog::Exception e)
    {
        logpp::Console::error(e.what());
    }

    auto window = Init(800, 600, "A Colored Cube");
    auto VertexArrayID = CreateVAO();

    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    static const std::vector<GLfloat> cube //Vertices for the cube
    {
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f, // triangle 1 : begin
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // triangle 1 : end
        1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f, // triangle 2 : begin
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f, // triangle 2 : end
        1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f
    }; 

    static const std::vector<GLfloat> cube_colors
    {
        0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
        0.609f,  0.115f,  0.436f,
        0.327f,  0.483f,  0.844f,
        0.822f,  0.569f,  0.201f,
        0.435f,  0.602f,  0.223f,
        0.310f,  0.747f,  0.185f,
        0.597f,  0.770f,  0.761f,
        0.559f,  0.436f,  0.730f,
        0.359f,  0.583f,  0.152f,
        0.483f,  0.596f,  0.789f,
        0.559f,  0.861f,  0.639f,
        0.195f,  0.548f,  0.859f,
        0.014f,  0.184f,  0.576f,
        0.771f,  0.328f,  0.970f,
        0.406f,  0.615f,  0.116f,
        0.676f,  0.977f,  0.133f,
        0.971f,  0.572f,  0.833f,
        0.140f,  0.616f,  0.489f,
        0.997f,  0.513f,  0.064f,
        0.945f,  0.719f,  0.592f,
        0.543f,  0.021f,  0.978f,
        0.279f,  0.317f,  0.505f,
        0.167f,  0.620f,  0.077f,
        0.347f,  0.857f,  0.137f,
        0.055f,  0.953f,  0.042f,
        0.714f,  0.505f,  0.345f,
        0.783f,  0.290f,  0.734f,
        0.722f,  0.645f,  0.174f,
        0.302f,  0.455f,  0.848f,
        0.225f,  0.587f,  0.040f,
        0.517f,  0.713f,  0.338f,
        0.053f,  0.959f,  0.120f,
        0.393f,  0.621f,  0.362f,
        0.673f,  0.211f,  0.457f,
        0.820f,  0.883f,  0.371f,
        0.982f,  0.099f,  0.879f
    };

/*  static const std::vector<GLfloat> cube
    {
        1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0
    };*/

    static const std::vector<GLfloat>::size_type triangleCount = cube.size() / VERTICES_IN_TRIANGLE;

    GLuint programID = LoadShaders(PathConverter::convert("shaders\\vertex.glsl").c_str(),
        PathConverter::convert("shaders\\fragment.glsl").c_str());

    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube.size(), &cube, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint colorbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube_colors.size(), &cube_colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    do 
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUseProgram(programID);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); //enable vertices
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, triangleCount, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // 2nd attribute buffer : colors
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            1,                                // attribute. No particular reason for 1, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                                // size
            GL_FLOAT,                         // type
            GL_FALSE,                         // normalized?
            0,                                // stride
            nullptr                          // array buffer offset
        );

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

        logpp::Console::debug("Drawing triangles");
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, triangleCount);
//      glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    } while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS
            && !glfwWindowShouldClose(window));

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

One last note, if I remove the color attribute and just set the entire cube to be red, it still gives the same dark blue screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems in the code:

You are disabling all vertex attributes before drawing. The calls to `glDisableVertexAttribArray` have to go after `glDrawArrays`, otherwise no data is attached when drawing.

The even better solution would be to move the VAO setup before the main-loop and never call `glDisableVertexAttribArray` at all. The pointers never change anyway, and storing the vertex attribute setup is exactly what a VAO is made for. Seems that the tutorial is very suboptimal in explaining/using them.

Another problem is that this line:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, triangleCount, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
```

should generate a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error since the size (second parameter) is only allowed to be 1, 2, 3 or 4. In your case triangleCount equals 12. The size describes how many elements **each** of the vertices should consume. So if the attributes is of type vec3, then it should be 3.

You should always check if `glGetError` returns any errors before asking on SO. That saves a lot of time because you already know which line is problematic.

Also note, that triangleCount does not actually contain the triangle count but the number of vertices.

Comment: The tutorial indeed doesn't give a lot of information on VAO's or glDisableVertexAttribArray. I'll try your tips out and see if it works. Also, do you know any place with good documentation on the VAO, or a better OpenGL tutorial that explains these things?

Comment: [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle) is quite good in my experience. Note, that the issues described in my answer are not the only problems as Rabbid76 pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

The first issue is that the 2nd paramter of [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) is the **size of the buffer in bytes**. Further `operator &` returns not a pointer to the data of a [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). You have to use [`std::vector::data()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/):

```
GLuint vertexBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
   cube.size()*sizeof(GLfloat),
   cube.data(),
   GL_STATIC_DRAW);  

GLuint colorbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    cube_colors.size()*sizeof(GLfloat),
    cube_colors.data(),
    GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Further [`glDisableVertexAttribArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xhtml), disables the generic vertex attribute array. This has to be done after the drawing. The `size` parameter of 
[`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) specifies the number of components per generic vertex attribute and must be 1, 2, 3, 4:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);  

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, triangleCount);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

Comment: This answer helped alot too, and if I could, I would accept it too. Thanks for your help!